# How to use a foreign key within a composite primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'd like to create a `composite primary key` with `hibernate`. Usually I'd go for  `@IdClass`.

But this time I want to use a `foreign key` also inside the composite primary key.

Question: is that possible at all?

Example:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    long id;
}

class CarPK implements Serializable {
    private int code;
    private String name;

    public CarPK(int code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CarPK.class)
class Car {
    @Id
    private int code;

    @Id
    private String name;

    //can I also mark "person.id" with @Id?
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_person_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_person"))
    private Person person; //assume car is shared
}
```

The person reference will show in database as `fk_person_id`. Is it possible to also add this column to the `primary key` of the `car` table?

So I'd be getting similar to: `CONSTRAINT car_pkey PRIMARY KEY (code, name, fk_person_id)`?

---

Update:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Person person;
```

Results in: `Property of @IdClass not found in entity path.to$Car: id`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can add the `@Id` to the join column, but you must use the key type in your `IdClass`. I'm doing exactly the same thing in my current project.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyIdClass.class)
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    private String key;

    @Column
    @Lob
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private MyOtherObject otherObject;
...
```

and

```
public class MyIdClass implements Serializable {

    private long otherObject;
    private String key;

...
```

`MyOtherObject.id` is a `long` in this scenario.

Comment: I tried as advised, but it does not work. Please see my update.

Comment: Did you add @Id to the Join column?